# How to add a registry key in the HKLM branch. Can add HKCU entries with no issues but with HKLM says access denied. Can the error be bypassed?

Tags: batch-file, registry

Example:

```batch
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
Set Name=test registry
title %Name%
START %WINDIR%\system32\reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Tim\%Name%" /v Path /t REG_SZ /d "%CD%"
pause
```

Comment: The `HKLM` root key is Windows system protected. You will need to run your batch file elevated, i.e. Run as administrator, or a higher privileged user, such as System. Also lines `2` and `3` should be one line i.e. `SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`, line `4`, should use the recommended syntax for defining variables, i.e. `Set "Name=test registry"`. Line `6` should read as `%WINDIR%\system32\reg.exe add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Tim\%Name%" /v Path /t REG_SZ /d "%CD%" /f`, there is no need whatsoever for the `start` command, or any point in excluding the extension for the executable file.

Comment: BTW, if the intended target subkey is really supposed to be `"HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"`, what is wrong with using the User environment instead? i.e. `"HKCU\Environment"`.